# Perlbrew Error: Can't Locate Pod/Usage.pm

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm having trouble installing Perlbrew.  I am getting the error message:

> "can't locate Pod/Usage.pm in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0xa031ea8)
>   /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /loader/0xa031ea8/App/ perlbrew.pm line
>   232."

I have been trying to find an answer and I saw one that his(her) problem was that the file was called pod instead of Pod.  (S)He just renamed the file.  How do I do that?  Or is there another way to fix this?
I also saw some other people mention that the Perl was an out of date version.  Do I need to update my Perl?  If so, how?
I know absolutely nothing about Perl or Perlbrew.  Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like to me you're using the fatpacked perlbrew executable, which does not packed `Pod::Usage` in there because it is expected to be part of any perl distribution newer since 5.6.0. I guess your perl distribution simply exclude Pod::Usage from the installation although I don't know why. You should be able to fix the issue by manually install `Pod::Usage`.

Comment: I tried to manually install, but it failed.  There were so many errors it quit.  I tried updating CPAN, but that also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Pod::Usage has been bundled with Perl since Perl 5.6.0. You have a broken (i.e. partial) installation of Perl, since it's missing that module.

Since your system is suppose to have it already, Pod::Usage is not bundled in the perlbrew installer like the other modules it uses.

Either install Pod::Usage first, or use the correct command line args for perlbrew (since it loads Pod::Usage when a help message needs to be displayed, from what I can tell).

Comment: I don't understand.  I am running Git Bash.  I am attempting to install perlbrew.  When I run the program, it gives me that error message.